# is there a utility method for this in commons-lang?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I searched for sometime but I couldn't find any

```
boolean isAlpha(final char character)
    {
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(character);
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
        case 'G':
        case 'H':
        case 'I':
        case 'J':
        case 'K':
        case 'L':
        case 'M':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
        case 'P':
        case 'Q':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
        case 'V':
        case 'W':
        case 'X':
        case 'Y':
        case 'Z':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is not from lang, but how about `return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`?

Answer (score 5):

Commons Lang has `CharUtils.isAsciiAlpha`, but perhaps you could just use `java.lang.Character.isLetter(char)` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)).  Not quite the same (the latter matches more than just A-Z ASCII), but may be enough for your needs.

Comment: do you know what they mean in the docs by: `Not all letters have case. Many characters are letters but are neither uppercase nor lowercase nor titlecase.`?

Comment: @MByD: Yes, that is a bit obscure, isn't it?  Something to do with international character sets, I'll wager.

Comment: I think he only wants ASCII characters to be returned.  I would assume the standard library methods would return true for non-ASCII characters as well.

Comment: `Character.isLetter` matches a lot of other characters besides ASCII lower/upper ([modifier, title case and other letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)), so this definitely isn't equivalent to the original.

Comment: @ColinD - but what are those other characters, it's not clear from the link you gave and it is actually interesting.

Comment: @MByD: Click on one of the categories (e.g. "Letter, Modifier") there and then click the "List" link on the page for the category to see the characters. Not real easy to find, I know.

Answer (score 2):

You  want [CharUtils.isAsciiAlpha](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils.html#isAsciiAlpha%28char%29).

- It should be faster than `StringUtils.isAlpha(String)` because you're not creating a new String object.
- You avoid the cost of converting to an uppercase char in your original method.
- It's more readable then range checks (which is how it's implemented).
- `java.lang.Character.isLetter(char)` will return `true` for certain non-Latin characters for which your method returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [StringUtils.isAlpha](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlpha%28java.lang.String%29)

That switch is pretty verbose, if I had to write it myself I'd make something like:

```
boolean isAlpha(final char c) {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(c)) != -1;
}
```

Comment: While the switch is certainly considerably more verbose than it needs to be, this is less efficient than it could be since it does a linear scan of the alphabet each time rather than just comparing endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

How about Character.isLetter()?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to check whether the given character is somewhere between A-Z, an easier way to do this would be to use regular expressions:

`Pattern.matches("[A-Z]", input)`

Where input is a `CharSequence`. More information on the Java `Pattern` class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Don't know how this would compare performance wise to the other options though.

Answer (score 1):

Character class provides many useful APIs. You need not convert the character. Few examples are

Character.isLetter(char ch)

Character.isLowerCase(char ch)

Character.isUpperCase(char ch)

Character.isDigit(char ch)

Character.isLetterOrDigit(char ch)